# How to scale time-series data in time domain (x-axis)?

Tags: python, time-series, scale, normalization, stock

I have built a Python program to download stock data. Now the stock data looks like this:

Date         High     Low     Open       Close      Volume  Adj Close

13/12/2018  0.156   0.150006 0.150006   0.1599996   620000  0.159999996

14/12/2018  0.156   0.150006 0.159996   0.1599996   408800  0.159999996

17/12/2018  1.66    1.389986 1.599971   1.5199981   339000  1.519999981

18/12/2018  1.57    1.399976 1.600057   1.4700029   115400  1.470000029

Now I want to scale the data first before plotting it. For example, if I have have a set of stock data in 3 months, is it possible to scale the graph to 1 month in length (scale the x-axis)?

The following is my code:

```
import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data as web 

start = datetime.datetime(2018,12,13)
end = datetime.datetime(2018,3,13)
data = web.DataReader(symbol, "yahoo", start, end)
data["Close"].plot(grid = True) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: How are you going to pot the data? Please provide you code.

Comment: I have updated the post with my code

Comment: This question deserved more attention. Di you find a solution?